# Clojure - Ring uberjar specify port

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

How can I generate a standalone ring `uberjar` that listens to a given port ?

When developing I launch my app with the following leiningen/ring command, in which I can specify the port :

```
lein with-profile dev ring server-headless 9696
```

Now I want to deploy it, so I ran :

```
lein with-profile prod ring uberjar 9696
```

But I got an error :

```
Error encountered performing task 'ring' with profile(s): 'prod'
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: uberjar/uberjar
```

So I added a `:port`in my `project.clj` :

```
:ring    {:handler img-cli.handler/handler
          :init    img-cli.handler/init
          :destroy img-cli.handler/destroy
          :port    9696}

lein with-profile prod ring uberjar
java -jar my-jar.jar
```

But then I see in the logs : `Started server on port 3000`

How do I generate an `uberjar` with the port that I want ?

*Note :* just in case, I'm using `compojure`.

Comment: It works for me, did you compile the jar after applying the changes in the project.clj?

Comment: @PauloBu Ah it turns out I had to use `lein with-profile +prod ring uberjar 9696`  (notice the `+`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my use of the profile was problematic.

A closer looks at the [profile documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) yields :

> To activate a profile in addition to the defaults, prepend it with a
>   +:
>
> `$ lein with-profile +server run`

Therefore I had to use `lein with-profile +prod ring uberjar 9696` (notice the `+`).